# About searching recursively in Perl

Tags: perl, search, find

I have a Perl script that I, well, mostly pieced together from questions on this site. I've read the documentation on some parts to better understand it. Anyway, here it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use File::Find;

my $dir = '/home/jdoe';
my $string = "hard-coded pattern to match";
find(\&printFile, $dir);

sub printFile 
{
   my $element = $_;
   if(-f $element && $element =~ /\.txt$/) 
    { 
        open my $in, "<", $element or die $!;
        while(<$in>) 
            {
                if (/\Q$string\E/) 
                    {  
                        print "$File::Find::name\n"; 
                        last;   # stops looking after match is found
                    }
            }
    }  
}
```

This is a simple script that, similar to grep, will look down recursively through directories for a matching string. It will then print the location of the file that contains the string. It works, but only if the file is located in my home directory. If I change the hard-coded search to look in a different directory (that I have permissions in), for example `/admin/programs`, the script no longer seems to do anything: No output is displayed, even when I know it should be matching at least one file (tested by making a file in `admin/programs` with the hard-coded pattern. Why am I experiencing this behavior?

Also, might as well disclaim that this isn't a really useful script (heck, this would be so easy with grep or awk!), but understanding how to do this in Perl is important to me right now. Thanks

**EDIT: Found the problem. A simple oversight in that the files in the directory I was looking for did not have .txt as extension. Thanks for helping me find that.**

Comment: This works for me as it stands.  (What probably means to check every little detail first.)  Another thing, you may want to try [File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/~rclamp/File-Find-Rule-0.34/lib/File/Find/Rule.pm)

Comment: Did you try debugging it? I'd first add an `else` with prints of all variables you use.  Perhaps make a test subdirectory in your home (and set `$dir` to it) with a few dirs and files, to check whether there is something about `/admin` (and to have less output to read through).

Comment: Wow. I feel like a fool. I don't know how I didn't see it before, but "checking every little detail" did reveal to me that all the files in `/admin/programs` don't end in `.txt`. My condition that they do was my problem. It works now.
Should I answer my own question here or should I just edit it to say what the problem was?

Comment: OK, good :)  It happens.  For this I'd just add a (prominent) note at the end.  It's a simple statement, may not warrant an answer.

Comment: @zdim do you know of a way I can return the name of the owner of file that the script finds?

Comment: For instance, `$id = (stat $file)[4]; $name = getpwuid($id)`.  (Can write in one statement.) See docs and search SO.  Note that `getpwuid` returns more in an array context.

Comment: Thanks, that works wonderfuly

Comment: Great :).  And, it's the _list context_ (and _not_ "array context") ... sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the desired output using the code you pasted by making few changes like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

You should always use them as they notify of various errors in your code which you may not get hold of.

Next I changed the line :

```
my $dir = './home/jdoe'; ##'./admin/programs'
```

The . signifies current directory. Also if you face problems still try using the absolute path(from source) instead of relative path. Do let me know if this solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This script works fine without any issue. One thing hidden from this script to us  is the pattern. you can share the pattern and let us know what you are expecting from that pattern, so that we can validate that.

You could also run your program in debug mode i.e.,

> perl -d your_program.

That should take you to debug mode and there are lot of options available to inspect through the flow. type 'n' on the debug prompt to step in to the code flow to understand how your code flows. Typing 'n' will print the code execution point and its result